# How do i format the title?

Tags: formatting, titles

```
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
    \scshape
    \TitleFont
            \bf abc  \end{center  \end{titlepage}
```

The title is to be written in 20 pt. Times New Roman font, centred and using the bold and “Small Caps” formats.  There should be 24 pt. (paragraph) spacing after the last line.

Anyone can help with this? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This fragment is not really useful. Where did you get this? `\bf` is a deprecated command for more than 20 years and it's a mixture of the newer commands `\scshape` and `\bf` which is even more weird

Answer (score 2):

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{report} %allows for title page
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx} %necessary for times new roman font
\usepackage{kantlipsum} %fake text generator

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \centering
    \fontsize{20}{24}\bfseries\scshape abc
\end{titlepage}

\kant{1-2} %fake text

\end{document}
```

Here is the title page it produces:

[image]

And here is the page after it, with fake text:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: **1.** If you move `\fontsize{20}{24}\selectfont` inside the `titlepage` environment, you don’t need to reset the size afterwards, since the group implied by the environment keeps the change local.  **2.** At this point, note that both `\scshape` and `\bfseries` issue `\selectfont` by themselves, so you can just say `\fontsize{20}{24}\bfseries\scshape`.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti, thank you, I made those changes.

Comment: Both the `\selectfont` commands you left in are now superfluous—they do nothing at all.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti, thanks for catching that! I fixed that as well.